# How to accept dynamic attributes (no of columns present in csv file)

Tags: unix

How to accept dynamic attributes (no of columns present in csv file)? But I want to do aggregation on particular column for ex cust_id, notification_type,count . And output of these should be stored in another csv file.

I have tried this

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$2 OFS $3]+=$4}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file_name
```

It is single line command. I want proper script.
It should be wrapped in script

like script_name.sh input_file output Folder

Sample file (actual file may in GB's)

```
 1,A,OTC,1
 2,B,RC,1
 3,C,PB,1
 4,A,OTC,1
 5,A,RC,1
 6,B,RC,1
```

Output Should be this:-

```
1,A,OTC,2
    ,RC,1
2,B,RC,1
3,C,PB,1
```

Comment: Your question mentions `dynamic attribute` but expected output/sample doesn't have any hint of the same. What is `dynamic`?

Comment: no of columns present in input csv file....but I want to do aggregations on particular column . the sample input is contains A- as Cust_id, OTC - Notification_type, 1-count .for sake of siplicity. but actual file contains no .of column